# Git .ignore not ignoring

Tags: git, macos

This is my .ignore file

```
.classpath
/.project/
/.settings/
/target/
.project
.settings
.target
```

Then I execute  `git add .`  and then after `git status` the files are not ignored

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   .classpath
    new file:   .ignore
    new file:   .project
    new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
    new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
    new file:   .settings/org.eclipse.m2e.core.prefs
```

Comment: It's .gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file needs to be called `.gitignore`